# PHP using PDO with two data tables

Tags: php, pdo

I want the status column to show the value "free" when there is no corresponding record in the `device_transactions` table, or there is a corresponding record in the `device_transactions` table with the `returned_date` blank field

My desired return result is like this
[image: My desired return result is like this]

That's all I can do right now
[image: That's all I can do right now]

How can I print row #4 while the `device_transactions` table has no corresponding records in the devices table?

The 2 data tables

Table devices:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Laptop01 |
| 2 | Laptop02 |
| 3 | Laptop03 |
| 4 | Laptop04 |

Table device_transactions:

| id | device_id | start_transaction_plan | end_transaction_plan | returned_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-12-10 14:20:43 | 2021-12-12 07:00:00 | 2021-12-12 9:30:23 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-12-11 10:10:20 | 2021-12-15 15:30:00 | 2021-12-16 7:30:45 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-12-12 19:03:00 | 2021-12-21 08:00:00 | NULL |

```
<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <?php
                    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT devices.id, devices.name, device_transactions.returned_date 
                         FROM devices, device_transactions WHERE devices.id = device_transactions.device_id ");
                    $sql->execute();
                    $result = $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $row) { ?>
                    <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php                             
                                if($row['returned_date'] !== null ){
                                    echo "free";
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "borrowed";
                                }
                            ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } 
            ?>
        </tbody>    
                
    </table>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What does `$row['returned_date']` contain against your expectation?

Comment: I want the result to return #row4 laptop04 | free, but since it has no records in the device_transactions table I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` to join devices and device_transactions table to get the all the results from the devices table. If there are no records in the device_transactions table, rest of the values will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `LEFT JOIN`, instead of `FROM devices, device_transactions` (which is an `INNER JOIN`).

```
SELECT devices.id, devices.name, device_transactions.returned_date 
FROM devices
LEFT JOIN device_transactions ON devices.id = device_transactions.device_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple LEFT JOIN and you'll get all the record:

OK I've made a little edit so my answer is not the same as already givven and this will help you to avoid checkinh if return date is null or not

```
SELECT d.id as deviceid, d.name as devicename, c.returned_date as returndate
FROM device d
LEFT JOIN device_transactions c ON c.device_id = d.id;
```

Edit of the query - so now if there is no record or return date is null you'll get 'free' as returntype else you get 'borrowed'(you can put whatever you want of course...) So now no need in php to check if $row['return_date'] == null just output the result from the query:

```
SELECT d.id as deviceid, d.name as devicename,
CASE WHEN c.returned_date IS NULL THEN 'free' ELSE 'borrowed' END as returntype
FROM device d
LEFT JOIN device_transactions c ON c.device_id = d.id;
```

See it working here

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32db15fbb2b00d780196ea879e6f7d20

Edited result:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4edc860aa39461f2c5e6655bbca77d66